# Eastern Character Set Causes Problems For SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, non-latin

I have a table with contents:

```
internalid  foreignWord
1   បរិស្ថាន
2   ការអភិវឌ្ឍសហគមន៍
```

And its schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CE_testTable](
    [internalid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [foreignWord] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
```

If I run:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [internalid]  ,[foreignWord] FROM CE_testTable where foreignWord = N'ការអភិវឌ្ឍសហគមន៍'
```

I get:

```
internalid  foreignWord
1   បរិស្ថាន
2   ការអភិវឌ្ឍសហគមន៍
```

Which is both rows, it should have only returned the row with "ការអភិវឌ្ឍសហគមន៍" which is "community development" in Cambodian.

It is a NVARCHAR column and I'm selecting where N'  etc?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the [collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188046.aspx) to `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS`.

You can specify collation for each column when you create the tables.

If you don't specify collation the columns will have the same collation that the database has.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CE_testTable](
    [internalid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [foreignWord] [nvarchar](50) collate Latin1_General_100_CI_AS NOT NULL
)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6eea1/1)

Comment: The table needs to be able to contain characters from any language.

Comment: @bendecko `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS` will also work.

Comment: +1 for SQL Fiddle.  Nice!   My collation is set to "SQLCollation
Latin1_General_100_CI_AS"  But on my machine it don't work. `SELECT TOP 1000 [internalid]
      ,[foreignWord]
  FROM [CE_testTable] where foreignWord = N'បរិស្ថាន'` gives me the whole table.

Comment: @bendecko it is not enough just to change the collation of the database. You also need to recreate any tables you already had created. The will keep whatever collation they got when created.

Answer (score 0):

Try the query without the N

```
SELECT [internalid],
       [foreignWord] 
FROM CE_testTable 
WHERE foreignWord = 'ការអភិវឌ្ឍសហគមន៍'
```

Comment: Does that work for you?  I tried that, it just returns no rows at all.

Comment: Strangely, your query returns no rows for me. Without the N it returns the correct row. What is your DB collation?

Comment: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.  This database might need to contain characters from any language in the world, not just Cambodian.

Comment: The collation [should not effect it](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1ec51a17-e837-4651-9538-6f3e889e7860/sql-server-collation-to-support-chinese-and-korean-language-along-with-english?forum=transactsql), as I can see the characters stored in there.  Something else must be up.

Answer (score 0):

I seems like SQL Server can't do what I'm asking of it.

Looking at the [comment](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1ec51a17-e837-4651-9538-6f3e889e7860/sql-server-collation-to-support-chinese-and-korean-language-along-with-english?forum=transactsql) from Erland Sommarskog, this explains my situation.  It stores OK, and I can see the rows in there.  But comparisons may fail.  They did.  So its a design level problem.  I can't have different collations on the table, so I can't compare.  For me this is not a problem it was only a PK that was erroring,  I can work around.

Comment: He also says that it is so in the old collations (version 80). But the new ones (version 100) has the necessary codepoints defined.